# python: convert json file into csv file that has mutliple table

Tags: python, json, csv

Here, let me show how my json data looks like:

```
filename: '1'
    [
    {
     name : 'a',
     compute_time : 10,
     sparsity : 5
    },
    {
     name : 'b',
     compute_time : 20,
     sparsity : 15
    } ,...
    ]

filename: '2'
    [
    {
     name : 'a',
     compute_time : 8,
     sparsity : 9
    },
    {
     name : 'b',
     compute_time : 25,
     sparsity : 8
    } ,...
    ]
```

From this `json` data, by loading multiple files, I want to make multiple tables in one `csv` file:

```
table a:

compute_time sparsity
 10           5
  8           9

table b:

compute_time sparsity
 20           15
 25            8
```

Here, "a" and "b" are different tables.

The reason why I should do this is that I need to load this `csv` file to `Excel`, and have to build a graph by using each table.

Is it possible to implement this kind of table in one `csv` file?

Comment: why don't you just create one table with a columns `names,compute_time,sparsity` and then play with the data in Excel? Its a lot simpler that way.

Comment: Your output doesn't look like a csv output. There must be row and column. Please clarify how your output must look like.

Answer (score -1):

A CSV file is a file that contains comma-separated values. There is no structure beyond that.

So of course you can put your data into that format:

```
table, a
compute_value, sparsity
10, 5
8, 9
table, b
compute_value, sparsity
20, 15
25, 8
...
```

But Excel won't know what to do with it - it won't understand that these are supposed to be multiple tables. It will just put these into rows and columns as it does with all csv data and you will have to manually move your cells that comprise the separate tables to different worksheets after importing the csv file, or do whatever else you want to use that format for. If you just want to create diagrams out of the data, that will be fairly simple because you can just manually select the various compute_time/sparsity cells.

But it seems to me that it would be easier to either create three columns:

```
name  compute_time    sparsity
```

or create one separate csv file for each name a, b c and so on.